# Interesting properties of functions whose derivatives at a point form a given sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, generating-functions

Suppose I have a sequence of real numbers $a_n$ and a real analytic function $f$ such that at a point $x$ (maybe 0), we have $f^{(n)} (x) = a_n$, for all $n$. Can we say anything interesting about this function in terms of $a_n$?

More specifically, are there any specific examples of sequences that might arise in other contexts where the corresponding function has interesting or surprising properties? For example, I first thought of this question when wondering what the properties of a function whose derivatives at a point form the Fibonacci sequence might be.

Comment: You might be interested in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma . Roughly this result says that any sequence $a_n$ is the taylor coefficients for some function $f$

Comment: Of course, the term "Taylor coefficients" is slightly misleading - in particular the power series with coefficients $a_n$ may not converge to the function $f$ itself in any neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Isn't f just the generating function of the $a_n$?